# From vector of pointers to a base type, return first element of derived type, casted as derived type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, vector, polymorphism

So I am working on a game engine of sorts, and I've been struggling with this issue for a while now. I'm not sure if it is a design issue, or I just don't have the necessary understanding of C++

Put simply, I have a vector of pointers to a type "BaseComponent". It consists of pointers to derived classes, AComponent, BComponent, etc. I was wondering if there is an elegant way to return the first element in the vector of a given derived type, and have it casted to the correct derived type. In pseudocode:

```
BComponent * bComp = getFirstElementOfType(vectorOfComponents, BComponent);
```

And it would automagically find the first element matching the type put in the second argument and return it **casted to the correct derived type**, or null if no component in the vector matches that type. I'm assuming we have to use templates for something like this (if it is possible at all) but after tinkering with it for a while now I haven't come up with anything that does the job. Hope that all makes sense, thanks for your time.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't make sense. The return type should be pointer or reference

Comment: Sounds like you need a co-variant return type. References and pointers can help with that. You may want to consider `shared_ptr` as well here

Comment: You've got a couple of answers that will do the job, but, generally if you find yourself doing "dynamic cast until something sticks" you have a deeper problem.  RTTI and dynamic casting is expensive, and you're producing a *game* engine.  More likely you should have a few virtual method(s) on the base class, like for eg: `CanShoot()` `CanMove()`, `IsScenery()`.  (Those seem likely properties of game objects.  :-) )

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner I agree that this is likely not an optimal solution, and is most likely a design based problem. Unfortunately I'm diving head first into both (what I consider) somewhat advanced C++/OpenGL AND game engine architecture. I have a ton to learn about all these things, and this project was supposed to be an ambitious opportunity to do just that. I'm doing my best, but I fully expect to have to refactor and restructure this project heavily as I go. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename Derived>
Derived* getFirstElementOfType(const std::vector<BaseComponent*>& components)
{
    for (auto* component : components) {
         auto* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(component);
         if (p != nullptr) {
             return p;
         }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

or

```
template <typename Derived>
Derived* getFirstElementOfType(const std::vector<BaseComponent*>& components)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(components.begin(), components.end(),
        [](BaseComponent* component)
        {
            return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(component) != nullptr;
        });
    if (it != components.end()) {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(*it);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

And call it that way:

```
BComponent* bComp = getFirstElementOfType<BComponent>(vectorOfComponents);
```

Comment: I just tried this and it appears to be doing the job perfectly, thank you!

Comment: While good, it can be simplified to a `find_if` + generic lambda (C++14).

Comment: @black: I generally agree, but here I found the code less clear (code added anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I would define a function similar to member function of class `std::exception`

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
```

and use it to find a pointer of the target derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this to return specific type:

```
template<typename TBase, typename UDerived>
UDerived* findFirstOfType(std::vector<TBase*> & items)
{
   for (auto item : items) {
      if ((auto d = dynamic_cast<UDerived*>(item)) != nullptr)
         return d;
   }
   return nullptr;
}
```

Called like:

```
Orange * orange = findFirstOfType<Fruit, Orange>(items);
```

Comment: I cleaned it up. Old habits die hard; since 2003 I've spent most of my time in C# and Java (ugg), so I missed the fact that C++03 added _declaration in the if condition_. I cannot believe I missed such an elegant feature! I did a decade of C++ from 1992 - 2002, but after that, I drifted to other languages and missed a lot of new features, until this year, when I realized how badly dated my C++ skills had become and ordered some new editions of my old books. I wonder what else I've missed!